# looking for (jQuery) painting plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for something that let the user paint on canvas, add there some text, images, background. (e.g. [1](http://www.bannersonthecheap.com/PowerDesign.aspx?T=376839576A4A4249504E757161423279394C423978673D3D&S=-1&M=-1&CID=5704),[2](http://print.staples.com/vp/ns/studio3.aspx?template=475964_AYR&ag=True&xnav=previews&xnid=image_146&rd=1),[3](http://www.banners.com/designer?templateId=561657&h=48.0&w=60.0&productId=1)).

It can be also paid. I found [this](http://wpaint.websanova.com/) which is good but I will have to do develop many things there.. I also found [this plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-pro-visual-banner-creator/7521301), but unfortunately it's for wordpress

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: Oh, but there's nothing else to describe in this type of questions. I was looking for something and I haven't found something normal.

Comment: You might try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: use google/bing/duckduckgo not stack overflow to find a random jquery library

Comment: @j08691 thanks, I will ask next time there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at fabric.js
It is a library for canvas drawing and there are many tutorials and demos out there.

http://fabricjs.com

Comment: thanks so much, that seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: If that's what you need, mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: well, there's limit in which I can't accept answer